# How to calibrate the input shape of my classification neural network?

Tags: python, keras

I'm getting this error:

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_27_input to have shape (20,) but got array with shape (3495,)

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.layers import Flatten
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import numpy as np


df = pd.read_csv('../input/nasa-asteroids-classification/nasa.csv')

df = pd.get_dummies(df)

X = df.loc[:, df.columns != 'Harzardous']
y = df.loc[:, 'Hazardous']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)


scaler = StandardScaler().fit(X_train)

X_train = scaler.transform(X_train)

X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)

model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(64, input_dim=(20), activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(32, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(16, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'))

compilation = model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=32)


scores = model.evaluate(X_train, y_train, verbose=False)
print("Training Accuracy: %.2f%%\n" % (scores[1]*100))
scores = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=False)
print("Testing Accuracy: %.2f%%\n" % (scores[1]*100))
```

How do i fix this?

The data set has 20 columns after get_dummies was applied to it, and it had 20 rows before it was applied.

Link to data set: https://www.kaggle.com/shrutimehta/nasa-asteroids-classification

Comment: you probably need to add the `nasa.csv` or a sample of it so that it can be answered..

Answer (score 0):

Your input dimension is not correct. Print the shape of X_train, y_train. They should have shapes `(X, 20)` and `(X,1)`, where X is a constant.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, you were right, when I ran the print statement, the input dimensions of X_train were: (8000, 2947).  Any idea how to change the input dimensions?

Comment: You have 2947 features in your data. Now you choose either change `
model.add(Dense(64, input_dim=(20), activation = 'relu'))` to `
model.add(Dense(64, input_dim=(2947), activation = 'relu'))` or add a line before fit `X_train = X_train[:,:20]`